# Acquiring screen or a part of the screen when accessory is connected in Android

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to create an accessory for Android. When connected to the phone it will launch an app to display some information. So far so good. I got a demo of this running.

I want this app to be visible and not be able to close unless you remove the accessory. I found some ways to do it but they are not guaranteed to work. Drawing over other apps requires a specific user action to be enabled like monitoring running processes.

[image]

Is there a non hacky solution for this type of problem?

I can compile my own version of Android and I can sign my app with the system signature if this can make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have option to edit Android source code, edit `core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java` file to modify `handleMessage()` method. Activities are launched, resumed, stopped and destroyed from this place. This method does much more than that but for your use case, this is where you can add your check to see if your hardware is connected to the Android phone and then choose to handle or ignore appropriate message.

One more way to achieve this if you have option to edit Android source code is to modify the status bar itself and add your view above status bar. Status bar is managed by SystemUI package which is under `frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/` I would start with this file `/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/super_status_bar.xml` and analyze further where it is used.

With first option, you can block all other apps from launching or resuming and with second approach, you UI will be part of Status Bar and other apps will continue to function as usual.